# Filtering Multi Array Table

Tags: lua

Let say I have 2 combo boxes. First combo box for a category and another one is for units. I made the array table like this:

```
Table1 = {
     Cat = 'Angle',
     Unit = {'Degree','Gradian','Radian'}}

Table2 = {
     Cat = 'Area',
     Unit = {'Acres','Hectares','Square centimeter','Square feet','Square inch',
        'Square kilometer','Square meter','Square mile','Square milimeter',
        'Square Yard'}}

Table3 = {
    Cat = 'Energy',
    Unit = {'British Thermal Unit','Calorie','Electron-Volts','Food-Pound',
        'Joule','Kilocalorie','Kilojoule'}}

Table4 = {
    Cat = 'Length',
   Unit = {'Angstrom','Centimeters','Chain','Phantom',
        'Feed','Hand','Inch','Kilometers','Link','Meter','Microns','Mile',
        'Milimemters','Nanometer','Nautical Mile','Pica','Rods','Span','Yard'}}
```

How to append the element to 1st combo box only for cat elements (category)?.
And 2nd combo box will automatically append the unit depending on the category on combo box 1?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is vague, plz refine the question. Do you want to combine all Units to 1st table in case it has Cat key?

Answer (score 0):

Simply throw all your tables into one array. I don't know how you need data for the combo boxes, but this example should help you.

```lua
local idx = 1 -- box index 

local boxValues = {
  {
    Cat = 'Angle',
    Unit = {'Degree','Gradian','Radian'}
  }, {
    Cat = 'Area',
    Unit = {
      'Acres','Hectares','Square centimeter','Square feet','Square inch',
      'Square kilometer','Square meter','Square mile','Square milimeter',
      'Square Yard'
    }
  }, {
    Cat = 'Energy',
    Unit = {
      'British Thermal Unit','Calorie','Electron-Volts','Food-Pound',
      'Joule','Kilocalorie','Kilojoule'
    }
  }, {
    Cat = 'Length',
    Unit = {
      'Angstrom','Centimeters','Chain','Phantom',
      'Feed','Hand','Inch','Kilometers','Link','Meter','Microns','Mile',
      'Milimemters','Nanometer','Nautical Mile','Pica','Rods','Span','Yard'
    }
  }
}

local catBox, unitBox = boxValues[idx].Cat, boxValues[idx].Unit
```

After selecting one value in the `catBox` you have to update `idx`.

Comment: Thanks, @csaar I have tried your solution and it works for catBox, item has added there. Anyway, I tried to solve the case by myself as on my answer the question post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the case. Note: I made this using CE Lua Script for GUI, etc.

```
    form = createForm()  -- create the form

    cbCategory = createComboBox(form) -- Category Combobox
    cbCategory.setPosition(10,10)
    cbCategory.Style = 'csDropDownList'

    cbUnitFrom = createComboBox(form) -- Source Unit Combobox
    cbUnitFrom.setPosition(10,40)
    cbUnitFrom.Style = 'csDropDownList'

    cbUnitTo = createComboBox(form)  -- Result Unit Combobox
    cbUnitTo.setPosition(10,70)
    cbUnitTo.Style = 'csDropDownList'

    -- show the form
    form.show()

    Category   = {'Angle','Area','Energy','Length','Power','Pressure','Temperature',
              'Time','Velocity','Volume','Weight','Bytes'}

    Angle       = {'Degree','Gradian','Radian'}
    Area        = {'Acres','Hectares','Square centimeter','Square feet','Square inch',
                   'Square kilometer','Square meter','Square mile','Square milimeter',
                   'Square Yard'}
    Energy      = {'British Thermal Unit','Calorie','Electron-Volts','Food-Pound',
                   'Joule','Kilocalorie','Kilojoule'}
    Length      = {'Angstrom','Centimeters','Chain','Phantom',
                   'Feed','Hand','Inch','Kilometers','Link','Meter','Microns','Mile',
                   'Milimemters','Nanometer','Nautical Mile','Pica','Rods','Span','Yard'}
    Power       = {'BTU/Minute','Food-Pound/minute','Horse power','Kilowatt','Watt'}
    Pressure    = {'Atmosphere','Bar','Kilo Pascal','Millimeter of Mercury','Pascal',
                   'Pound per square inch/PSI'}
    Temperature = {'Degree Celcius','Degree Farenheit','Degree Reaumur','Kelvin'}
    Time        = {'Year','Month','Week','Day','Hour','Minute','Second','Millisecond'}
    Velocity    = {'Centimeter per second','Feet per second','Kilometer per hour',
                   'Knots','Marc (at std.atm)','Meter per second','Miles per hour'}
    Volume      = {'Cubic centimeter','Cubic feet','Cubic inch','Cubic meter',
                  'Cubic yard','Fluid ounce (UK)','Fluid ounce (US)','Gallon (UK)',
                  'Gallon (US)','Liter','Pint (UK)','Pint (US)','Quart (UK)','Quart (US)'}
    Weight      =   'Carat','Centigram','Decigram','Dekagram','Gram','Hectogram','Kilogram',
               'Long ton','Milligram','Ounce','Pound','Short ton','Stone','Tonne'}
    Bytes       = {'Exabyte','Petabyte','Terabyte','Gigabyte','Megabyte','Kilobyte','Byte'}


    local itemsCB1 = cbCategory.Items
    local itemsCB2 = cbUnitFrom.Items
    local itemsCB3 = cbUnitTo.Items

    ----- Add items to Category combobox
    for i,v in ipairs(Category) do
     strings_add(itemsCB1, v)
    end

    cbCategory.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

   function cbUnit()
    local cat = cbCategory.ItemIndex
    if cat == nil then return nil end
     if cat == 0 then -- Angle
     cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
     cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
     for i,v in ipairs(Angle) do
      strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
      strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 1 then -- Area
    cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
    cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
     for i,v in ipairs(Area) do
      strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
      strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 2 then -- Energy
    cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
    cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
    for i,v in ipairs(Energy) do
     strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
     strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
    end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 3 then -- Length
     cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
     cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
     for i,v in ipairs(Length) do
      strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
      strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
     cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
     cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 4 then -- Power
    cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
    cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
     for i,v in ipairs(Power) do
      strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
      strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 5 then -- Pressure
    cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
    cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
     for i,v in ipairs(Pressure) do
      strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
      strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 6 then -- Temperature
    cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
    cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
     for i,v in ipairs(Temperature) do
     strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
     strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
    end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 7 then -- Time
     cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
     cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
      for i,v in ipairs(Time) do
       strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
       strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
     cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
     cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 8 then -- Velocity
     cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
     cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
      for i,v in ipairs(Velocity) do
       strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
       strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
      end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 9 then -- Volume
     cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
     cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
      for i,v in ipairs(Volume) do
       strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
       strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 10 then -- Weight
     cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
     cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
      for i,v in ipairs(Weight) do
       strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
       strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
     end
    cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
    cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0

    elseif cat == 11 then -- Bytes
     cbUnitFrom.Items.clear()
     cbUnitTo.Items.clear()
      for i,v in ipairs(Weight) do
       strings_add(itemsCB2, v)
       strings_add(itemsCB3, v)
      end
       cbUnitFrom.ItemIndex = 0
      cbUnitTo.ItemIndex = 0
    else
    return nil
    end
   end

    -- events handler
    cbCategory.OnChange = cbUnit
```